# Create table on cluster of clickhouse error

Tags: clickhouse

When I create table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE partition_v3_cluster ON CLUSTER perftest_3shards_3replicas(
ID String,
URL String,
EventTime Date
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(EventTime)
ORDER BY ID;
```

I get errors:

Query id: fe98c8b6-16af-44a1-b8c9-2bf10d9866ea

┌─host────────┬─port─┬─status─┬─error─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────     ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─num_hosts_remaining─┬─num_hosts_active─┐
│ 10.18.1.131 │ 9000 │    371 │ Code: 371, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There are two exactly the same ClickHouse instances 10.18.1.131:9000 i     n cluster perftest_3shards_3replicas (version 21.6.3.14 (official build)) │                   2 │                0 │
│ 10.18.1.133 │ 9000 │    371 │ Code: 371, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There are two exactly the same ClickHouse instances 10.18.1.133:9000 i     n cluster perftest_3shards_3replicas (version 21.6.3.14 (official build)) │                   1 │                0 │
│ 10.18.1.132 │ 9000 │    371 │ Code: 371, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There are two exactly the same ClickHouse instances 10.18.1.132:9000 i     n cluster perftest_3shards_3replicas (version 21.6.3.14 (official build)) │                   0 │                0 │
└─────────────┴──────┴────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────     ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
← Progress: 0.00 rows, 0.00 B (0.00 rows/s., 0.00 B/s.)  0%
3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.149 sec.

Received exception from server (version 21.6.3):
Code: 371. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: There was an error on [10.18.1.131:9000]: Code: 371, e.displayText() = DB::     Exception: There are two exactly the same ClickHouse instances 10.18.1.131:9000 in cluster perftest_3shards_3replicas (version 21.6.3.14 (official      build)).

And here is my metrika.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<yandex>
<remote_servers>
    <perftest_3shards_3replicas>
        <shard>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.131</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.132</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.133</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
        <shard>
         <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.131</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.132</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.133</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
        <shard>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.131</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.132</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
            <replica>
                <host>10.18.1.133</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
    </perftest_3shards_3replicas>
</remote_servers>
<zookeeper>
    <node>
        <host>10.18.1.131</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
    <node>
        <host>10.18.1.132</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
    <node>
        <host>10.18.1.133</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
</zookeeper>
<macros>
    <shard>01</shard>
    <replica>01</replica>
</macros>
</yandex>
```

I don't know where is wrong, can someone help me? Thank u

Comment: Your perftest_3shards_3replicas is incorrect. CH officially supports only one shard/replica per node. You need 9 servers for 3shards 3replicas

Comment: Thank u.  I change to 3 shards 1 replica, and it worked.  When I create the table,  the console print bellow:  what  do "num_hosts_remaining" and "num_hosts_active" mean?┌─host────────┬─port─┬─status─┬─error─┬─num_hosts_remaining─┬─num_hosts_active─┐
│ 10.x │ 9000 │      0 │       │                   2 │                0 │
│ 10.x │ 9000 │      0 │       │                   1 │                0 │
│ 10.x │ 9000 │      0 │       │                   0 │                0 │
└─────────────┴──────┴────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┘

Comment: it's live table, it shows updating info.
num_hosts_remaining -- how many hosts should execute but not yet. num_hosts_active -- how many hosts execute right now